# What is the search limit on LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin

When I am searching for any person name or company name on LinkedIn, after 3-4 results it shows:

> Serenesat, you’ve reached the commercial use limit on search.

My question is what is the limit on search? How many times an user can search? Is there any way to check the number of search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Commercial Use Limit on Search](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/52950/%7E/commercial-use-limit-on-search)

> If you reach the commercial use limit, your activity on LinkedIn indicates that you're likely using LinkedIn for commercial use, like hiring or prospecting. This limit is calculated based on your search activity since the first of the calendar month.
>
> **A progress bar appears in your search results when 30% of your searches are left, and continues to remind you in 5% increments**. After you've reached the limit, you can continue to search, but will see a limited number of results. Your free monthly usage resets at midnight PST on the 1st of each calendar month.
>
> **Note:** We're not able to display the exact number of searches you have left and we also cannot lift the limit upon request. Also note the warnings may not display if you run through the full amount of searches too quickly.